# SQL: Use results of one query in another query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I have a select statement and an update statement. What I would like to do in the update statement is set the value of 'recipes_saved' to the result of the select statement. I have tried to use this:

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `recipes_saved` = ('SELECT `recipe_1_name` FROM `carbohydrates`') WHERE `user_id` = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";

$data= mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error());
```

but the query fails.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: what do you want to set in recipes_saved? your query seems to set the recipe_1_name ...

Comment: @DrCopyPaste what appears is 'Query failed:'

Comment: sure there is only one entry in `carbohydrates`? otherwise ur subselect fails because you cannot compare a result set with `=`

Comment: @Sarah Al in ur code u concatenate `QUery failed` with a detailed error from mysqli what is the value of that?

Comment: @Aris i want to set the value of recipes saved to the value of recipe_1_name

Comment: @DrCopyPaste there is only one value in the recipe_1_name column

Comment: then why the subselect anyways? did you try to replace `('SELECT `recipe_1_name` FROM `carbohydrates`')` with that value just for curiosity?

Comment: yep sure @DrCopyPaste I will try to use the value directly but I wanted to know how I can combine an update and select query

Comment: @SarahAl the combination itself looks alright, but as I said you need to ensure that that subselect only results in one value or it fails, also what could trouble you is the quotation marks you are using, i think the additional `'`around the `SELECT` are suberfluous, what about `user_id` is that really a string? if not get rid of the `'` there too

Comment: @DrCopyPaste i tried to directly use the value of recipe_1_name but I am still getting Query failed:

Comment: Does Users have `user_id` as well like Carbohydrates table?

Comment: @Edper nope user_id is only in the users table

Comment: So, what's the common field then between the two tables if any?

Comment: @Edper there is no common field, does there have to be?

Comment: No, does not have to be, because if it does you could use `UPDATE <table1> JOIN <table2> ON <table1>.commonfield=<table2>.commonfield SET field=value`. Have you tried to use LIMIT 1 by the way to limit to 1 record only in your subquery?

Comment: ahhh i see thanks for that. I just tried using LIMIT 1 at the end of the select query but the query still fails

Comment: @SarahAl did you look into trying to remove the superfluous `'` from your query?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste i removed the ' around the select query (this is what my current query is $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `recipes_saved` = SELECT `recipe_1_name` FROM `carbohydrates` LIMIT 1 WHERE `user_id` = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";)

Comment: @SarahAl Have you tried copy pasting (sorry @DrCopyPaste) my answer to see if it works?

Comment: @Edper yep i did didn't work:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an extra `'` in your **'SELECT** and also in your **FROM** `carbohydrates`' and use LIMIT again like:

Try to copy the query below:

```
 $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `recipes_saved` = (SELECT `recipe_1_name` FROM `carbohydrates` LIMIT 1) WHERE `user_id` = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
```

You could of course remove the back tick if you want to make it less cluttering, like:

```
 $query = "UPDATE users SET recipes_saved = (SELECT recipe_1_name FROM carbohydrates LIMIT 1) WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
```

Comment: @SarahAl Try do `echo $query;` and copy paste the output in your OP so that we could examine closely what really is wrong with it.

Comment: this is the output UPDATE users SET recipes_saved = (SELECT recipe_1_name FROM carbohydrates LIMIT 1) WHERE user_id = '37'

Comment: thank you all it works now. Turns out it was a problem with a connection to the database (original connection was working but had to change it to because of the query)

Comment: @SarahAl is  `user_id ` numeric or text data type?

Comment: Glad that it work for you now @SarahAl. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Comment: thanks @edper it is working now. I had to change how I was connecting to the database (was originally using this $link = mysql_connect('localhost:8889', 'root', 'root')
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('help_me_be_healthy') or die('Could not select database'); and changed it to this   $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'help_me_be_healthy') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($dbc));

Comment: You're welcome @SarahAl. I hope you're not showing your password by that code that you posted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you do not need so many quotes in your query. Try:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET recipes_saved = (SELECT recipe_1_name FROM carbohydrates) WHERE user_id='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
```

It would also be useful to log in to your database directly (either command line or a GUI client) and try running the query:

```
UPDATE users SET recipes_saved = (SELECT recipe_1_name FROM carbohydrates) WHERE user_id='username'
```

and see if that works.

Comment: thanks @matt i ran the following on my database: UPDATE users SET recipes_saved = (SELECT recipe_1_name FROM carbohydrates) WHERE user_id= 20 and this worked. Removed the unnecessary quotes from the query in my code and it still doesn't work

Comment: i'm sure the user id is correct as I am echoing this before doing the query

Comment: In that case I think the issue is with your error reporting - assuming $dbc is your connection and is configured correctly, try changing mysqli_error() to mysqli_error($dbc)